# How to chmod a directory so that files put in it later will be automatically excusable

Tags: linux

Please note that I want files that WILL be put in this folder automatically excusable.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean executable?

Comment: Use ACL. There's already a solution for this kind of question. http://superuser.com/questions/264383/set-file-permissions-so-that-new-files-inherit-same-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to excuse files?  It's not like the filesystem cared if they go missing.
Joke aside, you can't.  see `man umask` for something which comes close, but it does not work on a per-folder basis.

Edit: Then again, you could of course run a script (by cron, or using something more fancy like inotify) to periodically or on-access make all files executable in that folder.

Comment: Thanks. This is why: html files on http server  must have executable bit on to use SSI virtual include.